# Nautilus and Nemo ssh connection error: Timed out when logging in

Tags: networking, ssh, nautilus, nemo

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 64bit with the latest version of Nautilus and Nemo.
Both of them raise the error

> Timed out when logging in

while trying to connect via ssh...

In terminal the connection works.

How can I fix it?
There is a way to raise that connection time? Or disable it?